# Filter Complex Objects in PrimeNG Turbo Table

Tags: angular, filter, google-cloud-firestore, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Lets say I have a table and I'm pulling in a list of clients. Maybe one of the parameters is an address object which contains parameters like city, state, zip etc. I can easily make any of those values appear in the table (E.g client.address.city) but because they are part of the address object I am unable to filter or sort by those values.

This is currently what Material 2 offers for flattening out the data, giving users the ability to filter/sort.

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (client: Client, filter) => {
        let dataStr = client.step + client.name + client.interest.industry + client.interest.package + client.address.city + client.address.state + client.origin;
        return dataStr.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1; 
      }
```

How can I achieve something like this with primeng's turbo table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until upcoming milestones try to address a [related custom filter feature request](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5119), I don't think a custom filter similar to the Material 2 approach is possible.

You could transform or extend the original table data object into a PrimeNG-specific object representation of your table data where each column definition is (or additional col defs are) the flattened/concatenated/CSV (etc.) representation that you want to filter using PrimeNG DataTable/TurboTable filterMatchMode types.

You probably will not display the actual filter-friendly col def value. Instead you would render what you like from the related original table data object values inside the ng-templates that switch on the filter-friendly column def field name.

I use this approach for filtering multiple values that need to be displayed in a single table cell for a row, e.g. currency prices on a single product. I display stacked divs in the table, but allow filtering as if they are a CSV list of values.

```
            // This is actually PrimeNG DataTable but TurboTable approach is similar

            <ng-template *ngIf="col.field === 'csvPriceCurrencyCodes'" let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                <div *ngFor="let price of data?.prices">
                    {{ price?.currency }}
                </div>
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template *ngIf="col.field === 'csvPriceAmounts'" let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                <div *ngFor="let price of data?.prices">
                    {{ price?.price | delimitNumber:2 }}
                </div>
            </ng-template>
```

Another example is a `col.field` with a name like `enabledProduct` that I can replace with one of two CSV strings that represent a range of typical boolean values that people could type into the PrimeNG table filter input that is set to `filterMatchMode` `contains` either `0,n,no,off,false,disabled` or `1,y,yes,on,true,enabled` but all that is displayed visually is a giant checkmark icon for enabled items.

(I generally use the PrimeNG 'Dynamic Columns' approach listed in the docs.)

Comment: Thank you for this!  What I ended up doing was flattening out the data coming in specifically for sorting / filtering and that did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

you can easily access complex object with  primeng globalfilter 
in this way :
 add on the p-table the costume attribute  [globalFilterFields] and fill it with array of columns header - and what awesome is it accept dots!!! so you can go deep inside complex object

```
<p-table [globalFilterFields]="['notes','price','carType.name','nameOfCustomer']" >
```

Comment: i dont know who devote to my answer - but he probably never work with primeng